# image not displaying in HTML

Tags: html, image

I am trying to display image in an HTML page using img tag. code is :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE html 
 PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>hi!</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>

     <img src="images/a.jpg" alt="MISSING JPG" /> 
     <img src="images/b.jpg" alt="MISSING JPG" /> 
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Image a.jpg is displayed correctly but for b.jpg it diplays "MISSING JPG". Problem comes only on ie 8. On fireforx it works fine.  I have verifies location of both image files. Both images open fine when directly clicked. I have tried repairing a.jpg using JPEG repair tool irfanviewer and other phot editors but it doesn't work. I tried to repair image using one of the online image repair tool, then it worked.  I have to display large number of jpeg files and all of them are giving problem.  Not sure how to repair JPEG files.

I have uploaded a.jpg at loacation "http://s20.postimage.org/s0n2lakq5/image.jpg". It loads fine from this URL but not from disk.

Comment: Don't know whether this is correct. This is what I noticed; check your file extension(consider about capitals). for **a** you have used **jPG** and for **b** you have used **jpg**. Try to use like this **b.jPG** (since you said **a** is working)

Comment: I have check extension and upper.lower case. It doesn't work.  Im sure problem is with image itself.  It loads properly from URL of uploaded file but deosn't load from disk.  URL is : http://s20.postimage.org/s0n2lakq5/image.jpg

Comment: Cannot access the URL.It is broken

Comment: sorry. here it is : [link](http://s20.postimage.org/s0n2lakq5/image.jpg)

Comment: Don't know why. Still I cannot access the URL. even the domain. :(

Comment: I have added URL in my main question

Answer (score 1):

So you are saying the b is showing up, but not a? At first glance you don't have .jpg (all lower-case) for a.

What you have - a.jPG

What you *should* have - a.jpg

My guess is that modern browsers know what you are trying to achieve here and parse it correctly for you, while older browsers get confused.

If this doesn't fix it, then please upload your images somewhere and provide us a url to its location. Without actually looking at the image itself there is no way to determine if its been compromised somehow.

Comment: I have uploaded image. URL is : "http://s20.postimage.org/s0n2lakq5/image.jpg" It loads in HTML if I give direct postimage link. If I save image to local disk and try to load, it doesn't work.